# Avoiding MySQL deadlock in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, deadlock

Using Django on a MySQL database I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

The fault rises in the following code:

```
start_time = 1422086855
end_time = 1422088657
self.model.objects.filter(
    user=self.user,
    timestamp__gte=start_time,
    timestamp__lte=end_time).delete()

for sample in samples:
    o = self.model(user=self.user)
    o.timestamp = sample.timestamp
    ...
    o.save()
```

I have several parallell processes working on the same database and sometimes they might have the same job or an overlap in sample data. That's why I need to clear the database and then store the new samples since I don't want any duplicates.

I'm running the whole thing in a transaction block `with transaction.commit_on_success()` and am getting the `OperationalError` exception quite often. What I'd prefer is that the transaction doesn't end up in a deadlock, but instead just locks and waits for the other process to be finished with its work.

From what I've read I should order the locks correctly, but I'm not sure how to do this in Django.

What is the easiest way to ensure that I'm not getting this error while still making sure that I don't lose any data?

Answer (score 9):

Use [select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) method:

```
samples = self.model.objects.select_for_update().filter(
                          user=self.user,
                          timestamp__gte=start_time,
                          timestamp__lte=end_time)


for sample in samples:
    # do something with a sample
    sample.save()
```

Note that you shouldn't delete selected samples and create new ones.  Just update the filtered records.  Lock for these records will be released then your transaction  will be committed.

BTW instead of `__gte`/`__lte` lookups you can use [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
samples = self.model.objects.select_for_update().filter(
                          user=self.user,
                          timestamp__range=(start_time, end_time))
```

Comment: I just tried out `select_for_update()` (and `__range`) but I'm still seeing deadlocks. N.b. `samples` isn't coming from the db, but is from the actual processing job. The db is just used to store some of the information collected from a much larger dataset.

Comment: Depending on the situation, consider trying select_for_update(skip_locked=True).  If your case allows it, you can avoid a deadlock situation and deal with it another way, or not at all.  In my case, the update was not essential and the system automatically recovered on the next update.  Just something for the toolbox.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid deadlocks, what I did was implement a way of retrying a query in case a deadlock happens.

In order to do this, what I did was I monkey patched the method "execute" of django's CursorWrapper class. This method is called whenever a query is made, so it will work across the entire ORM and you won't have to worry about deadlocks across your project:

```
import django.db.backends.utils
from django.db import OperationalError
import time

original = django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper.execute

def execute_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 3:
        try:
            return original(*args, **kwargs)
        except OperationalError as e:
            code = e.args[0]
            if attempts == 2 or code != 1213:
                raise e
            attempts += 1
            time.sleep(0.2)

django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper.execute = execute_wrapper
```

What the code above does is: it will try running the query and if an OperationalError is thrown with the error code 1213 (a deadlock), it will wait for 200 ms and try again. It will do this 3 times and if after 3 times the problem was not solved, the original exception is raised.

This code should be executed when the django project is being loaded into memory and so a good place to put it is in the `__ini__.py` file of any of your apps (I placed in the `__ini__.py` file of my project's main directory - the one that has the same name as your django project).

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: I'm afraid this hook **only repeats the last DB query** that resulted in Deadlock error. But Database **reverts the whole transaction** in such case. Thus, if executing a more complex logic consisting of multiple DB queries inside one `atomic()` block, this will result in unwanted behavior because after all the block may finish without some of the statements being recorded in the DB.